# An array of subdomain urls

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of urls, I want to say : if any of these urls, are a subdomain of `example.com` then add it to another array.

How can I check every domain if it is a subdomain of `example.com` in php?

Comment: Take a look at `strripos()`.

Comment: @HamZa can u say please how to do it ?

Comment: Read the docs and use common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$all_subdomains = array('test.example.com', 'blog.xyz.com');
$matched_subdomains = array();
foreach ($all_subdomains as $subdomain) {
    if (preg_match('/\.example\.com$/i', $subdomain)) {
        $matched_subdomains[] = $subdomain;
    }
}
print_r($matched_subdomains);
```

Comment: added array to hold matched subdomains. example here: http://debug.studiotate.com/28375511